# Make a phone call without pressing the call button

Tags: android, phone-call

I have a class that makes a call to an emergency number. I get to the "call" app with the phone number already passed in, but i still have to press the Call Button to start the call.

Is there a possibility where i don't actively have to press the call button but it does it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emergency numbers always require that the user presses a button explicitly. This is a security feature.

See [docu for ACTION_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL)

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for the information. There is no possibility to circumvent this security feature or?

Answer (score 2):

As henry has mentioned in his answer, its only possible call emmergency number using **ACTION_DIAL**. Howerver you can call anyother number directly using this intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "ur phoneNumber here"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Dont Forget to Add this Permission to the Manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: According to the docu (see link in my answer) it is not possible for emergency numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Permission required is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: According to the docu (see link in my answer) it is not possible for emergency numbers.